# Jboss 7.1.1 startup throws Unable to read the logging config

Tags: jboss7.x

I am using `JBoss7.1.1.Final` with `jdk 1.8.0_20`. When i run standalone. it throws error as

> "Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:/c/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jbos s-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFo undException: \c\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configurat ion\logging.properties (The system cannot find the path specified))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final does not work with Java 8 https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279.

If you're required to use Java 8 I'd suggest using the JBoss AS 7 predecessor [WildFly](http://wildfly.org). Starting with WildFly 10 Java 8 is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can start using OpenJDK 1.8 from JbossAS 7.4.1, Oracle and IBM from JBoss AS 7.3.3  https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663

Comment: FWIW that's for JBoss EAP 6.4.1 and higher.